# Show DIV message at every "X" number of minutes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmuc6mhc/1/) for visual understanding. I'm trying to display on the top left a message every 5 minutes. I want it to flicker a few times and then fade away slowly. I'm not that good in CSS and thought also it should be done with JavaScript? I want the message to be inside a rounded corner box. Below is my CSS.

thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
  <div id="container">
    <div id="map_size" class="map_size">   
      <div id="msg">
        new records available.          
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*body*/
body{
  margin:0px auto;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
}

/*container for all divs inside*/
#container {
  width:1450px;   
}

/*map size*/
#map_size{
  width:1190px;
  height:1300px;
  background:#0099FF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

/*msg*/
.station_info_ {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width:  275px;
  border:4px solid black;
}
```

JS:I dont want the message to show when the page is laoded until 5 minutes has passed. Afterwards, I want it to show every 5 minutes. How is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('document').ready(function(){
      window.setInerval('test()',3000);
     });

    function test(){
     $('#msg').toggle();
    } 
 </script>
```

Comment: This can be done using Javascript. Show us your attempts with it ans we will take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing `setInterval()` after `setTimeout()` has finished.

**Working code snippet:**

(I have set the timings to 3 seconds just so that you can check it quickly. You can change it to 5 minutes.)

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    
    $('#msg').hide();
    
    window.setTimeout(
        function(){
            $('#msg').show();
            setInterval(function(){ $('#msg').toggle(); }, 3000);
        }        
        ,3000);
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
}

/*container for all divs inside*/
#container {
    width:1450px;   
}

/*map size*/
#map_size{
    width:1190px;
    height:1300px;
    background:#0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

/*msg*/
.station_info_ {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:  275px;
    border:4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="map_size" class="map_size">   
        <div id="msg">
            new records available.          
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5tofed9g/)

Comment: awesome all I had left to do is start with .hide() lol!! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval(function(){ alert("After 3000 milliseconds"); }, 3000);`

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval):

> .setInterval() calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.

**Edit:**

1. You have to create your own popup div (Search Google) and display a message.
2. Then you can use `.hide()` to hide that div after displaying

You cannot close an alert box with `javacript` until user interacts with it.

Comment: LOL. I was typing that very thing just now!

Comment: @alda1234 the 3000 is 3 seconds for minutes try doing something like this  300000

Comment: tis fine! Good for you gave you +1

Comment: @Harikrishnan Please use links from MDN. W3Schools is not an ideal source. :)

Comment: thanks for the solution, it works but what I am trying to do is, not display the message once the page is loaded.. after the 5 minutes I want it to show the message and go away. How is it possible? I updated my code. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to add some animations you could use `animate.css` like in the following demo. You could also use jQuery animations but animate.css is easier to use and a lot eaiser to try out different animations.

You only have to change the animation names.

Have a look at [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) webpage for available animation styles.

The tip from Hari Krishnan works perfectly. (I've used it in the demo.)

The line `$msg.show().removeClass().toggleClass(flag ? inAnimation : outAnimation);` is a bit tricky.
It shows the div and toggles to the css stored in `inAnimation`. In the next interval the flag is falsy and the css stored in `outAnimation` will be used.
The `removeClass()` is required to have no other stlyes in the div before applying the animation css.
(There is no `hide()` function because css `fadeOut` is hiding automatically.)

The demo is available in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/7cxfmda9/).

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
    var $msg = $('#msg');
    var displayTime = 0.1; // in minutes 0.1 = 6 seconds / 1 = 1 min.
    var flag = true;
    
    $msg.hide();

    setInterval(

    function () {
        var inAnimation = 'fadeIn animated';
        var outAnimation = 'fadeOut animated';
        //console.log(flag);
        $msg.show().removeClass().toggleClass(flag ? inAnimation : outAnimation);
        flag ^= true;
    }, displayTime * 1000 * 60);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
/*container for all divs inside*/
 #container {
    width:1450px;
}
/*map size*/
 #map_size {
    width:1190px;
    height:1300px;
    background:#0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
/*msg*/
 .station_info_ {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 275px;
    border:4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.2.0/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="map_size" class="map_size">
        <div id="msg">new records available.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice one, thanks a lot I will look into it for sure! :)